# Android: Statically link against libstdc++

Tags: c++, android, linux, android-ndk

my program compiles nicely for Android, however when I try to copy it to the Android emulator, it gives the following error:

```
knight666@Katja-Linux /media/Data/Shared/Galaxians $ acpy Galaxians.android
Filename: 'Galaxians.android'
819 KB/s (420657 bytes in 0.501s)
link_image[1638]:   825 could not load needed library 'libstdc++.so.6' for '/system/sbin/Galaxians.android' (load_library[984]: Library 'libstdc++.so.6' not found)CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE
```

`acpy` is a small script I wrote that does the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILEPATH=`dirname $1`
FILENAME=`basename $1 .c`

echo "Filename: '$FILENAME'"

adb push $FILEPATH/$FILENAME /system/sbin/$FILENAME
adb shell chmod 777 /system/sbin/$FILENAME
adb shell /system/sbin/$FILENAME
```

Here is how I build my application:

```
oem@androiddev /media/YoghurtGum/Tests/Galaxians $ sudo make
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -static-libgcc -g -Wall -Werror -O2 -w -I ../../YoghurtGum/src/GLES -I ../../YoghurtGum/src -c src/Alien.cpp -o intermediate/Alien.o
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -static-libgcc -g -Wall -Werror -O2 -w -I ../../YoghurtGum/src/GLES -I ../../YoghurtGum/src -c src/Bullet.cpp -o intermediate/Bullet.o
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -static-libgcc -g -Wall -Werror -O2 -w -I ../../YoghurtGum/src/GLES -I ../../YoghurtGum/src -c src/Game.cpp -o intermediate/Game.o
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -static-libgcc -g -Wall -Werror -O2 -w -I ../../YoghurtGum/src/GLES -I ../../YoghurtGum/src -c src/Player.cpp -o intermediate/Player.o

arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
-Wl,--entry=main,
-dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker,
-rpath-link=/home/oem/android-ndk-r3/build/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/lib,
-rpath=../../YoghurtGum/lib/Android,
-L/home/oem/android-ndk-r3/build/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/lib 
-nostdlib 
-lstdc++ 
intermediate/Alien.o 
intermediate/Bullet.o 
intermediate/Game.o 
intermediate/Player.o 
../../YoghurtGum/lib/Android/libstdc++.a 
../../YoghurtGum/bin/YoghurtGum.a 
-o bin/Galaxians.android
```

Line breaks are only for clarity, none exist in the actual output.

YoghurtGum is my game library that already statically and dynamically links to `libstdc++`.

When I remove `lstdc++`, the program doesn't compile because it can't find the library.

Is there a way to link to `stdlibc++` statically or link the application to the correct dynamic library in the emulator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a modification of the ndk with support for exceptions, RTTI and stdlibc++.

http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r3.php

The other alternative involves porting just what you need, by hand... eek!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've figured it out in the past year. ;) Crystax was the answer, but it has problems on its own. It's one release behind (the official NDK is at r5, Crystax is at r4) and it's not well documented.